# Finding the Time Range to restrict the events occuring on same time in calendar. (django)

Tags: django, database, sqlite, django-queryset, datetimerangefield

I want to **restrict overlapping** of events occurring on same date and same time. I want to show the overlapping error to the user when he registered an event on same date having same time. I am unable to query the time range between **start_time** and **end_time**. What is the best way to restrict overlapping?

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
user         = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title         = models.CharField(max_length=200)
description   = models.TextField()
date          = models.DateField()
start_time    = models.TimeField()
end_time      = models.TimeField()
created_date  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
group        = models.ForeignKey(Group , on_delete= models.CASCADE , null= True , blank=True)
priority        = models.ForeignKey('Priority' , on_delete= models.CASCADE , null= True , blank=True)

@property
def get_html_url(self):
    url = reverse('event-detail', args=(self.id,))
    return f' <a href="{url}"> {self.title} </a>'

def create_event(slef):
    return f"http://localhost:800/event/create/"

# def get_event_in_current_date(self):
#     print(Event.objects.filter(date= self.date))
#     return Event.objects.filter(date= self.date)

@property
def get_all_events(self):
    if Event.objects.filter(date= self.date).count() >1:
        url = reverse('event-all', args=(self.date, ))
        return f' <a href="{url}"> ... </a>'
    return ""

@property
def get_all_events_by_group(self):
    print(self.group)
    if Event.objects.filter(date= self.date , group= self.group ).count() >1:
        url = reverse('event-all-group', args=(self.date, self.group.name ))
        return f' <a href="{url}"> ... </a>'
    return ""



def __str__(self):
    # print(self.date)
    return str(self.date)
```

**views.py**

```
class CreateEvent(LoginRequiredMixin , View):
def post(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
    start_time         = request.POST.get('start_time')
    end_time           = request.POST.get('end_time')
    title              = request.POST.get('title')
    description        = request.POST.get('description')
    date               = request.POST.get('date')
    priority          = request.POST.get('priority')
    GROUP_REQUEST_SLUG = str(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    group_slug         = GROUP_REQUEST_SLUG.split('/')[-2]
    group = Group.objects.filter(slug = group_slug).first()
    priority = Priority.objects.create(scale =priority )
    
    
    if group is None:
        Event.objects.create(date= date , title = title , start_time= start_time , end_time=end_time ,description= description , user= request.user , priority = priority)
        messages.success(request, "Event has been createds .")
        
    else:
        Event.objects.create(date= date , title = title , start_time= start_time , end_time=end_time ,description= description , user= request.user , group= group , priority = priority)
        messages.success(request, f"Event has been created  in {group}")
        return redirect('switch-group' ,group_slug )
    return redirect('calendar')
```

Answer (score 0):

Django provides a `range` [lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range)

```
Event.objects.filter(date__range=["2011-01-01", "2011-01-31"])
```

or

```
Event.objects.filter(pub_date__time__range=(datetime.time(8), datetime.time(17)))
```

or you also can use `gt` , `gte`, `lt`, `lte` [lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt)

I think you have to use  `unique_together` for your `Event` model ([more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together)).

```
unique_together = ['date', 'start_time']
```

Comment: thanks for response. Thats not working in my case can u please elaborate precisely? that would be very kind of uh.

Comment: What not working? Can you specify your question?

Comment: i have used unique_together in Models.py as Meta class but still thtats not working.

Comment: although that's not giving any errors! I really want to get time(user input) and want to compare it with the time present in my DB.So no event could be overlapped by time.